# An example for a case where $\left \| AB \right \|_{HS}\ > \left \| A \right \|_{HS}\left \| B \right \|_{HS}$

Tags: matrices, normed-spaces

I need to **disprove** that $\left \| AB \right \|_{HS}\ \leq  \left \| A \right \|_{HS}\left \| B \right \|_{HS}$. (HS= Hilbert-Schmidt norm)

I've tried several random $2\times 2$ matrices without much success.

Is there any smart way of coming up with such matrices, apart from guessing?

Can someone give an example? Thank you...

Comment: What's $\lVert \bullet\rVert_{HS}$ ?

Comment: Because, if it is [this](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Hilbert-SchmidtNorm.html), then I think you cannot disprove it: if I recall correctly, that norm is indeed sub-multiplicative.

Comment: It is indeed Hilbert-Schmidt norm. I'd be glad if you can link to a proof

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Hilbert-Schmidt norm is submultiplicative so no such example exists. This follows by applying the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality to all pairs of row vectors of $A$ and column vectors of $B$; concretely

$$\lVert AB \rVert_{\mathrm{HS}}^2 = \sum_{i, j} \left(\sum_k a_{ik} b_{kj}\right)^2 \leq \sum_{i, j} \sum_k a_{ik}^2 \sum_m b_{mj}^2 = \sum_{i, k} a_{ik}^2 \sum_{m, j} b_{mj}^2 = \lVert A \rVert_{\mathrm{HS}}^2 \lVert B \rVert_{\mathrm{HS}}^2.$$

Comment: Apparently someone made a mistake. thanks!